# Confused why delta ∆Q and dQ don't make sense for heat Q

Tags: thermodynamics, heat

In my chemistry teacher's notes, some notations concerning the heat $Q$ are marked as inappropriate.

> $Q$: yes
>
> d$Q$: no
>
> $\delta Q$: yes
>
> $\Delta Q$: no

In the second bullet in the screenshot below, why does ∆Q have an "x"" beside it and others have a check mark? I had tried to understand but I failed to do [image: You should find the third point I'm talking about in screenshot attached]

Comment: I'd think twice before using notes where a simple and correct $$Q<0$$ is replaced with  invented abomination like $$Q=\ominus\mathrm{ve}$$

Comment: Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/22171

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140395/discussion-on-question-by-sid-confused-why-delta-q-and-dq-dont-make-sense-for).

Answer (score 6):

Heat is not a state function. For any state function $X$ (like enthalpy, entropy, Gibbs energy, etc.), it makes sense to use d$X$ (total or exact differentials) and $\Delta X$. For quantities like heat or work that are path-dependent, you use the $\delta$ notation (inexact differential), e.g. when integrating along a path.

---

$Q$ and $W$ already include implicit delta ($\Delta$), being specific forms of energy (ex)change.

In contrary to the operator $\mathrm{d}$, operator delta $\Delta$ is not  limited to functions with exact differentials. So $\Delta Q$ (similarly $\Delta W$ )could still be used for cases like $\Delta Q = Q_2 - Q_1$.

Answer (score 0):

Intuitive approach: If you have amount of money $M_1$ in your bank account at some time, then you receive some income $I$ and give out a loan $L$, what equation can you write relating this quantities and your new amount of money $M_2$?

Hopefully you'd come up with some equivalent form of $M_2 = M_1 + I - L$, which we can write as $\Delta M = I - L$. This is a conservation law (we made the implicit assumption that money cannot be created or destroyed, only transferred and accumulated or depleted).

What sense would the terms $\Delta I$ or $\Delta L$ make? I'm sure in some context it could make sense to talk about your "change in income" or "change in amount loaned", but that would require comparing two scenarios, here we just want to perform a simple balance on a single system over a well-behaved time period. The income and loan are amounts of money that are *transferred*, they are ways in which *the actual quantity* changes. That is, only $M$ changes, and $I$ and $L$ are contributions to that change.

Maybe it would be more rigorous to think of the first law this way (standard scientific sign convention):

$$\Delta E = \Delta E_{work} + \Delta E_{heat}$$
[Change in internal energy] = [energy change due to energy transfered as work] + [energy change due to energy transfered as heat]

Then give a simpler symbol for amount of energy transferred as work: $\Delta E_{work} \equiv W$ and likewise for heat.